# Unable to set state hook using useDispatch hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useEffect hook to dispatch action to my redux store on component load. Here is code:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const hotelList = useSelector(state => state.hotels)
const [updatedList, setUpdatedList] = useState([...hotelList])

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchHotels())
// setUpdatedList(hotelList) -- I've tried using this line here but still gets empty array
  }, [])
```

It works fine because when I try to do `{console.log(hotelList}` I get array of objects from the redux store.

However, when I try to do `setUpdatedList(hotelList)` or even set initial state it does not work and I get empty array. How can I fix it?

P.S just to clarify I am 100% sure that action was correctly dispatched to the store as I can see the results in console.log as well as in redux dev tools.

Comment: Can you please share more of your code? You mention using `setUpdatedList`, can you show how you're using this in your component?

Comment: Hello, its that commented out line inside useEffect. I am trying to set it as a state hook just after the action gets dispatched to the store.

Comment: UPDATE: I've realized that calling setUpdatedList just after dispatch inside useEffect does not work because yet at this time this async code is not finished. How can I make sure that setUpdatedList(hotelList) will be executed only when dispatch(fetchHotels()) is fully completed?

Comment: What is the relation between `hotelList` and `[updatedList, setUpdatedList]`? Why do you need the latter?

Comment: If the async is the problem, try changing your useEffect to
`useEffect(async () => {
    await dispatch(fetchHotels());
   setUpdatedList(hotelList)  
  }, [])
`